# Is necessery use object type when use linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I found alot linq method use Generics, for example:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
```

I can use it like:

```
XX.Where<Person>();
```

But I also can use it like:

```
XX.Where();
```

So Is there any different put  on there?  Is there more faster? or not any different? because it already build correctly when building project??

**UPDATE:**

Why do I ask it, because I remember when use net3.5 some people told me , if you're not use Generics, there is happening Boxing and unboxing, it will let you application more slow....**

Comment: It's the same. If you don't explicitly say what the generic arguments are, it will try to get them from the arguments.

Comment: You only need the `<Person>` when the generic argument can't be inferred from the expression (which is rare).  There is no performance difference.

Comment: You *are* still using generics, you're *not* boxing the values, even if you *weren't* using generics your object looks like it should be a reference type, meaning it wouldn't be boxed at all, and even if it were being boxed, the performance impact is very unlikely to actually be problematic, as boxing is just not nearly as expensive as a lot of people like to make it out to be.

Comment: For the -1 out there, this is a legitimate question to ask and doesn't deserve the -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a form of *type inference.*  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx for a detailed explanation of the process.